# using group_by in dplyr to merge two character column into one

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a data frame like the case below, and I would like to use `group_by` function of the `dplyr` in a way that `Gender` and `Income` merged into one column.

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Gender, ~var1, ~var2, ~ var3, ~Income,
  "Bangladesh", "F", 2.5, 3, 1.5, "LM",
  "Bangladesh", "M", 4.5, 4.3, 2.7, "LM",
  "Laos", "F", 2.7, 3.2, 6.5, "LM", 
  "Laos", "M", 3.5, 5.1, 8.2, "LM", 
  "Ghana", "F", 8.5, 5, 7.5, "LM",
  "Ghana", "M", 4, 6.7, 1.3, "LM",
  "China", "F", 4.3, 6.1, 2.5, "UM",
  "China", "M", 6.2, 2.8, 6.8, "UM",
)
```

I have the option to use `group_by` to join two numeric clolumn like this:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Country, subgroup = var1 + var2) %>%
  summarise()
```

But I cannot do that with character clolumn:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Country, subgroup = Gender + Income) %>%
  summarise()

#Error: ! non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

what I would like after groupuing by is something like below

```
df2 <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~subgroup, 
  "Bangladesh", "F", 
  "Bangladesh", "M", 
  "Laos", "F",  
  "Laos", "M", 
  "Ghana", "F", 
  "Ghana", "M", 
  "China", "F", 
  "China", "M",
  "Bangladesh", "LM", 
  "Bangladesh", "LM", 
  "Laos", "LM",  
  "Laos", "LM", 
  "Ghana", "LM", 
  "Ghana", "LM", 
  "China", "UM", 
  "China", "UM",
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output isn't exactly summing the two columns, but rather transforming it from "wide" to "long". You can get your desired output in base R using `mapply` with `c` to combine them or using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` (more popular):

Base R:

```
mapply(c, 
       df1[c("Country", "Gender")],
       df1[c("Country", "Income")])

      Country      Gender
 [1,] "Bangladesh" "F"   
 [2,] "Bangladesh" "M"   
 [3,] "Laos"       "F"   
 [4,] "Laos"       "M"   
 [5,] "Ghana"      "F"   
 [6,] "Ghana"      "M"   
 [7,] "China"      "F"   
 [8,] "China"      "M"   
 [9,] "Bangladesh" "LM"  
[10,] "Bangladesh" "LM"  
[11,] "Laos"       "LM"  
[12,] "Laos"       "LM"  
[13,] "Ghana"      "LM"  
[14,] "Ghana"      "LM"  
[15,] "China"      "UM"  
[16,] "China"      "UM"
```

`dplyr`/`tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(df1, c(Gender, Income), values_to = "subgroup") %>%
  select(Country, subgroup)
```

Output (organized by country)

```
   Country    subgroup
   <chr>      <chr>   
 1 Bangladesh F       
 2 Bangladesh LM      
 3 Bangladesh M       
 4 Bangladesh LM      
 5 Laos       F       
 6 Laos       LM      
 7 Laos       M       
 8 Laos       LM      
 9 Ghana      F       
10 Ghana      LM      
11 Ghana      M       
12 Ghana      LM      
13 China      F       
14 China      UM      
15 China      M       
16 China      UM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reframe()` if your row order doesn't matter:

```
dplyr::reframe(df1,  subgroup = c(Gender, Income), .by = Country)
#> # A tibble: 16 × 2
#>    Country    subgroup
#>    <chr>      <chr>   
#>  1 Bangladesh F       
#>  2 Bangladesh M       
#>  3 Bangladesh LM      
#>  4 Bangladesh LM      
#>  5 Laos       F       
#>  6 Laos       M       
#>  7 Laos       LM      
#>  8 Laos       LM      
#>  9 Ghana      F       
#> 10 Ghana      M       
#> 11 Ghana      LM      
#> 12 Ghana      LM      
#> 13 China      F       
#> 14 China      M       
#> 15 China      UM      
#> 16 China      UM
```

Comment: Thanks @moody. Is there a way to have an `All` category in subgroup column? By `All` I mean aggregated values in Gender each country. In this way `subgroup` column have three distinct level to choose for each country, `Gender` (`F` or `M`), `Income` (`LM` or `UM`), and `All` for all male and female.

Comment: Also, I got a different outcome from your code. I copy and paste this but I don't know why this produce a `tibble: 8 X 2` of `country` and `subgroup`.